# Schedule notation (time ranges)

Tags: java, datetime, notation

I have some code which needs to do things based on a schedule:  e.g. during business hours do X, after hours do Y.  The schedule will be defined by our customer's so I need a notation which can be written by people and parsed by my program.  I'm thinking of something like:

```
12/25:0730-1730 Do Y
[Mo-Fr]:0730-1730 Do X
[Mo-Tu]:1730-0730 Do Y
Fr:1730-Mo:0730 Do Y
```

There will definitely be weekly variation.  Yearly variation (holidays) seems likely.  I would like a notation that is efficient and flexible.

I also need java code which will parse the time ranges and tell me which range a given date time is in.

I've searched the web and found nothing.  Closest is CRON notation, which is not quite what I need.

Any one know of an existing notation definition and implementation?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you going to run something on a specific time or "allow" something to happen between the interval?

Comment: Hmmm, if you know the CRON notation well it pretty expressive. Also, consider using Quartz instead of building your own scheduler.  It supports a Cron like syntax http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/CronExpression.html, as well as other methods of scheduling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Java [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) (Scala wrapper [scala-time](http://github.com/jorgeortiz85/scala-time/tree/master))  is a powerful library for time calculations. You could look at the [google-rfc-2445](http://code.google.com/p/google-rfc-2445/) which does something like what you are asking for (?).

If you are looking for a Java scheduler http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/ is a good option.

Comment: Thanks for those references.  Looks like joda-time has less than what I need but could be a good starting point.  The google code has more than what I need but maybe I could strip out the really useful objects.  There is only one client who needs this.  I may give up on an elegant notation an go with something difficult for people but easy to program.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will find something out of the box. In such cases it's better to do the implementation by yourself and have a full control of the code. You can use [antlr](http://www.antlr.org/) to create a parser.

Add a notion of priority to your syntax. Then it will be easier to schedule someting

```
01.01.2011-31.01.2011 prio 1 do-idle-stuff
[Mo-Fr]               prio 2 do-work
[Sa-Su]               prio 2 weekend
10.02.2011-17.02.2011 prio 3 go-on-holidays
```