# Is there a library for time interval composition in Java or Scala?

Tags: java, datetime, scala, scheduling

I am looking for a library for Java or Scala allowing boolean composition of time intervals, to define periods like "Monday to Friday except 23:00—23:20 UTC". Something like crontab interval definition, but with arbitrary compositions allowed. Is there anything like that?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136097/schedule-notation-time-ranges/5136257#5136257

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if there is something exactly like that, but as a base you could look at [JODA Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), an extensive Java Library for all kinds of Date/Time handling.

---

**EDIT:**

i just remembered that the [Play! Framework](http://www.playframework.org/) uses CRON expressions. It contains a CRON expression parser that may be useful to you:

https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/libs/Time.java

Also it got this parser from Quartz, an open source job scheduler, that may also be of interest to you: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/

Answer (score 4):

There are [Scala wrapper for Joda Time](https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-time) and [scala-datetime](https://github.com/soc/scala-datetime), a ongoing implementation of JSR-310.

Comment: Actually there are [several Scala wrappers for Joda Time](https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time) since there was some doubt about scalaj-time no longer being maintained.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's joda-time, not joda-date, but it definitely has interval mechanisms - so you'd be down to parsing the interval formats you're interested in.

Note also that Stephen has a new project, based on JSR-310, called "threeten" - see http://threeten.sourceforge.net/.